# ("offset"issue?) Error message occurred when fitting a Poisson mixed-effect model (PIRLS loop resulted in NaN value)

Tags: r, mixed-models, poisson

I am trying to use a Poisson mixed-effect model to examine the effect of reading English words (Words, N =8, each word repeated 10 times) multiple times (because there were multiple trails for each word) under 3 types of conditions. In my study, trials had different durations as each participant read texts freely with no time limit. However, when I included "trial_time" into the model, an error like beneath came out.
May I know why the error occurred? May I know if there is an issue with my model? It seems that this error occurred everytime when I added this offset function.

Study Design: It is a between-subject design with each participant randomly assigned into one of the 3 conditions reading 8 English words.
Predictor: reading condition (categorical, n=3)
Outcome variable: fixation count( the number of times eyes visit an English word, continuous)

```
Error in (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L, maxit = 100L, : 
PIRLS loop resulted in NaN value
```

My R command:

```
Count_1<- glmer(FIXATION_COUNT~ CONDITION + offset(log(TRIAL_TIME))+ (1|PARTICIPANT) + (1| WORD), family = poisson (link = "log"), data = WORD_DATA)

summary(COUNT_1)
```

Part of my data:

```
PARTICIPANT CONDITION   WORD    COUNT   TRIAL_TIME
1   0   wallow  5   8250
1   0   wallow  0   10801
1   0   wallow      2860
1   0   wallow  0   5384
1   0   wallow      1650
1   0   wallow  0   3096
1   0   wallow  0   423
1   0   wallow  3   4516
1   0   wallow  1   2132
1   0   wallow  0   398
2   0   wallow  1   3037
2   0   wallow  0   2197
2   0   wallow  0   5767
2   0   wallow  1   7233
2   0   wallow  1   6294
2   0   wallow  0   5379
2   0   wallow  0   4448
2   0   wallow      486
2   0   wallow  0   1547
2   0   wallow  1   477
10  1   wallow  2   842
10  1   wallow  0   663
10  1   wallow  4   3150
10  1   wallow  0   2138
10  1   wallow  0   2513
10  1   wallow  0   1759
10  1   wallow      3396
10  1   wallow  0   1499
10  1   wallow  0   842
10  1   wallow  2   658
```

The same error occurred after I added a random effect term (CONTEXT|WORD) into the model (there is no random slope for CONDITION by participant because each participant was exposed to only 1 condition)

```
Count_2<- glmer(FIXATION_COUNT~ CONDITION + offset(log(TRIAL_TIME))+ (1|PARTICIPANT) + (1| WORD) +(CONDITION|WORD), family = poisson (link = "log"), data = WORD_DATA)
```

[This is the link to my dataset:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K09ct1xF8BYhbje70JE3B0G8F-bUPma0/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101013857224174075258&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: Do you have any trial times of zero by any chance ... ? Can you post the full data set somewhere/can we have a reproducible example? It's a bit of a long shot, but can you try `offset(log(TRIAL_TIME/1000))` ? ( That *shouldn't* make a difference, but it might ...)\

Comment: @Ben Bolker Hi Ben, thank you for your reply. These are eye-tracking data so there are several trial times of zero, meaning the participant did not spend any time reading some trials.  I added an offset of TRIAL_TIME because I assume that the number of fixations (i.e., fixation count) readers made to a word while reading hinges on the amount of time they spent on reading a trial. I have added a link to my datafile in my edited question. Would you please take a look at it to see what the possible issue is? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a programming problem, and is arguably an "infelicity" in `glmer` (it should warn you that you have non-finite offsets in your model), but it's fundamentally more of a stats problem.

The model you're constructing assumes that fixation counts are *strictly proportional* to trial time.

- If fixation counts are always zero when trial time is zero, then these observations aren't providing any information and you can remove them from your data prior to fitting the model.
- If fixation counts are *not* always zero when trial time == 0, this is an impossible outcome under the model (non-zero outcome from a Poisson sample when the mean is equal to zero). (This is the case in your data; there are about as many non-zero as zero responses in the zero-trial-time cases.)

Mathematically, the problem is that `log(0)` is `-Inf`, and this screws up the calculations at some point.

What should you do about this? That's probably a question for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). Given that a small fraction of your data are zero-time (101 out of 4261 complete cases), you could probably get away with something like `offset(log(TRIAL_TIME + 0.5))` ...